# OpenSceneGraph can't start because osg80-osgd.dll is missing

Tags: c++, openscenegraph

Would appreciate some help finally tackling this problem in Visual 2010. I am trying to run a sample project that should run fine, only I get an error popup with the message

**The program can't start because osg80-osgd.dll is missing from your computer.**

when I go to run it. I checked to make sure I have the folders specified correctly under the path directory in Environment variables, and I also have libs correctly listed under project configuration. I finally used dependency-Walker to analyze the dll, and found some errors but I am not certain how to interpret the errors or what to do with the information given. Would appreciate some help correcting the errors highlighted by dependency-Walker so I can get my project to run fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're mixing 32-bit an 64-bit binaries, IE, you have a 64-bit build and 32-bit DLLs?

Comment: I have checked and rechecked that. I made sure to point to only the x86 build binaries both specified in path variables and in the project's property configuration.